# ПК завис при загрузке kubuntu

Tags: linux, kubuntu

Купил новый ПК. Решил установить Kubuntu. Во время установки компьютер остановился на 64%.  И завис. Ничего не работает. В том числе кнопка выключения на системном блоке. Будет ли что-нибудь, если отключить питание при установке? Как быть?
PS прождал уже 1 час

Comment: Ну если уже завис, то терять видимо уже нечего и отключение питания ничего принципиально не изменит

Comment: При установке Xubuntu была такая же ситуация, перезагружал системник и все работало.